# Is there an equivalent doEvents() for R language

Tags: r, debugging, console, citrix, doevents

I am a web developer/SQL guy, who is tasked at providing help desk support for a gaggle of statisticians using various statistics languages which is not my forte.

I have an R stat guy who is processing a large dataset.  Processing will take days.  Platform is citrix projected R (not studio) onto a virtual desktop.  He is getting what appears as intermittent lockups.  While his processing is tight he does have periods every few minutes where he is not calling a heavy duty processing function.  I was thinking if there is a way in R to do a "doevents()" like they have for VB and c# where CPU cycles can be diverted to the R GUI?  Not as a permanent solution but as a means to recover the GUI for periods of time so we can see what's going on.  Currently he is adding logging messaging to his application so we can at least where application is stalling.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like you need to use `browser` at those parts of the code. Check `?browser`.

Comment: @LyzandeR;  Thanks  LyzandeR, will check it out.